# SQL search for result in two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query that returns a 1 column table.

```
select distinct id_usuario from preference where valor1=? and tipo like '%master%'
```

I need to check if the returned lines are in other table. And keep only the records that are in both tables.

How to do that using only basic SQL sintax?

For instance suppose that my first query returns:

```
12
99
16
13
```

Now I search for these results in table TableName on column ColumnName and I find only these numbers

```
99
16 
50
```

So I will keep only as final result

```
99
16
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [common table expressions (CTE)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms190766(v=SQL.105).aspx) to create a temporary reusable table and populate it for queries. **Example:**

```
with cte as
(
    select distinct id_usuario as col1 from preference where valor1=? and tipo like '%master%'
)
select * from cte where col1 in (select ColumnName from tableName)
```

Comment: cte is Common table expressions. Its a way of creating temporary tables to work with . [Here's some details](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms190766(v=SQL.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
select columnname from tablename 
where exists (
select distinct id_usuario 
from preference where valor1=? and tipo like '%master%')
```

You can use `exists` or `in` to check for those id's from the other table.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT columnName 
FROM table2 
WHERE columnName IN 
 (SELECT columnName FROM table1)
```